# Why does changing font-size and line-height screw up my HTML layout?

Tags: html, css

I could post the code if it would be helpful (but it's a lot). Basically, if I change line-height or font-size to a really big value, it breaks my html layout - specifically, my DIVs seem to be getting bigger...But I don't have text in those divs.

Comment: Can you put the HTML and CSS up on jsfiddle?

Comment: try changing to: "body { line-height: 100em; }"

Answer (score 7):

Any inline element will pay attention to [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height):

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

In your case, you have `<img>` elements (which are inline elements by default) inside your `<div>` elements (which are block containers).

Changing the `font-size` implicitly alters the pixel value of `line-height`, the default is `line-height: normal` and that means:

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element.

So, altering either the `font-size` or `line-height` will change the vertical space that your inline elements occupy.